# data insertion in mysql by php

Tags: php, mysql

In my code is just insert some data into mysql database by php. All data are inserted but only two column's data are not inserted.
My code::

regi.php
  // form design

```
 <html>
    <form action="regi_pp.php"  method="post">
      Student Name <input name="st_name" type="text" id="st_name">
       Father's Name  <input name="f_name" type="text" id="f_name">
      Mother's Name <input name="m_name" type="text" id="m_name">
      Faculty  <input name="faculty" type="text" id="faculty">
      Department <input name="department" type="text" id="department">
      Session <input name="session" type="text" id="session">  
     Dormitory  <input name="dormitory" type="text" id="dormitory">  
    Registration No <input name="regi_no" type="text" id="regi_no"> 
     Email  <input name="email" type="text" id="email"> 
     pass:<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass">  
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
 </html>
```

after submit ::

```
 <?php 
    $st_name=$_POST["st_name"];   // name
    $st_father=$_POST["f_name"];   // father name
    $st_mother=$_POST["m_name"];   // Mather name
    $faculty=$_POST["faculty"];     // faculty name
    $dept=$_POST["department"];     // department name
    $session=$_POST["session"];     // session  
    $dormitory=$_POST["dormitory"];  // dormitory 
    $regi_no=$_POST["regi_no"];     //regi number
    $email=$_POST["email"];         //  email
    $pass=$_POST["pass"];          // password

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");   // mysql connection

    mysql_select_db("ppp", $con);    // database connection

    // here all value insert but '$regi_no', '$email' are not inserted and '$pass' value only insert if $pass value is number 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO regf            VALUES('$st_name','$st_father','$st_mother','$faculty','$dept','$session','$dormitory','$regi_no','$email','$pass')") or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: What happens when you print out your SQL statement and run it in the database? And your code is wide open for SQL injections, too - you should really look at using `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Show us your database layout (SQL Create).

Comment: it print actual value that i write, but it don't insert into database

Comment: Did you ever meet [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: Read about preventing SQL injection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved, I assign regi_no, email as integer, now i assign this as varchar i hope it would be worked

Comment: Whatever you're doing here, **STOP** immediately and read up on how to use PDO or `mysqli` and proper SQL placeholders. What you're doing here is reckless and will lead to severe problems at some point in the future. It takes all of thirty minutes to absorb how to use `mysqli` correctly and it will save you from a whole world of hurt when someone uses a [SQL vulnerability exploit tool](http://sqlmap.org/) on your application.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? what is the Question?

Answer (score 1):

What if in the dormitory I entered `Saint Philip Dormitory'); DROP TABLE regfs;--`? What do you think will happen?

Your code is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** Extensions instead.

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    // insert one row
    $name = 'one';
    $value = 1;
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with single quotes.

Comment: Disappointed you didn't use your example dormitory in your sample code, but nice demonstration of PDO.